# Significance of colours in photoelasticity

Tags: optics, visible-light, polarization, stress-strain, birefringence

I already checked similar question at Physics SE, but none gives me a clear answer, also it is a bit difficult for me to understand it from wikipedia as I couldn't find relating material to my Question

Question: Do colours have any significance in photoelasticity, do they have something to do with varying density regions in a material or something like that?, Does the density of colour lines (irrespective of colour) per unit area give a sense of strain in that area?

If above were true, How would it apply to the below protractor.

[image: Image of a protractor undergoing a photoelasticity test]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual use of an image like the one you posted is to identify nonuniform regions of the material.  The amount of variation in  polarization at any location on the protractor is related to the amount of strain, or nonuniformity, in the material itself.  As explained in [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/68/what-causes-polarised-materials-to-change-colour-under-stress?rq=1) , there are a couple underlying optical principles which cause the color changes.

Comment: Do colours relate to some property in that region like red depicting high density or high strain region or something like that.                                                  In the link that you mentioned it mentions birefringence as a reason relating to refractive index which depends on density of medium. so does it mean above holds good

Comment: No, it's the rate of change of color, which can be related to the rate at which the separation of interference planes changes (so as to produce constructive interference at different wavelengths

Comment: OK, then that would mean for the above picture that just left of zero is a high stress region? Am I right Here?